# Get deck of picture cards to load in a grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a cardArray to hold card objecct. then loop through the cardArray to create images as cards. I am appending the grid div to hold the card images as children. then I have an event listener for the shuffle button. I cannot get the cards to load into the grid.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
<title>Shuffle Picture Cards</title>
<script>

//create cards
const cardArray =[
{name:'bass',
img:'images/bass.png'},
{name:'bass',
img:'images/bass.png'},
{name:'burger',
img:'images/burger.png'},
{name:'burger',
img:'images/burger.png'},
{name:'jamaica',
img:'images/jamaica.png'},
{name:'jamaica',
img:'images/jamaica.png'},
{name:'mbappe',
img:'images/mbappe.png'},
{name:'mbappe',
img:'images/mbappe.png'},
{name:'napali',
img:'images/napali.png'},
{name:"napali",
img:'images/napali.png'},
{name:'racecar',
img:'images/racecar.png'},
{name:'racecar',
img:'images/racecar.png'},
]

//shuffle card array
cardArray.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())

//shuffle from shfl-btn
const shuffle = document.getElementById('shfl-btn');

//eventListener for click on shuffle button
shuffle.addEventListener('click', createBoard);

//get grid
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');

//create cards board
function createBoard() {
for(let i=0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
    var card = document.createElement('img')
    card.setAttribute('src', 'images/astart.png')
    //card.setAttribute('data-id', i)
    //card.addEventListener('click', flipCard)
    grid.appendChild(card)
}
createBoard();
}


</script>
<style>
body{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: center;
}
img{
    height:100px;
    width:100px
}

button{
    padding:10px;
    width:80px;
    border:solid black 2px;
    border-radius:4px;
    cursor:pointer;        
    margin-top:20px;
}
    
        
.grid{
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    border:solid blue 4px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.shfl-btn{
    align-items: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:400px;    
}
.shuffle{
    margin-left:160px;
    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Shuffle picture cards</h1>
<div class="grid" id="grid">     
</div>

<div class="shfl-btn"><button class="shuffle">shuffle</button></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I created a cardArray to hold card objecct. then loop through the cardArray to create images as cards. I am appending the grid div to hold the card images as children. then I have an event listener for the shuffle button. I cannot get the cards to load into the grid.

I am expecting the cards to load vua the createBoard function and to shuffle when shuffle button is clicked.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your `shuffle` button's event listener is isn't working as I can see in this line:

```
//shuffle from shfl-btn
const shuffle = document.getElementById('shfl-btn');
```

... you are trying to get the button element using the ID `shfl-btn` but I can see in the HTML code on this line:

```
<div class="shfl-btn"><button class="shuffle">shuffle</button></div>
```

... you have the `shfl-btn` as the class, so therefore adding `id="shfl-btn"`, would fix it.

---

```
//create cards board
function createBoard() {
for(let i=0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
    var card = document.createElement('img')
    card.setAttribute('src', 'images/astart.png')
    //card.setAttribute('data-id', i)
    //card.addEventListener('click', flipCard)
    grid.appendChild(card)
}
createBoard(); // <--- Here
}
```

I see here in this function, you are calling `createBoard()` repeatedly, like an endless loop, so calling it only **once** outside the function would stop it  from looping over and over again.

---

And will also mention that adding these two lines inside the top of the `createBoard()` function would help get rid of the following problems:

```js
grid.innerHTML = ""; // Remove all the images from the grid before appending new ones.
cardArray.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()); // Shuffle it each time createBoard function is called.
```

---

### Edit

I see that the pictures aren't loading... Well its because on this line in the `for` loop:

```js
card.setAttribute('src', 'images/astart.png');
```

...you are setting each of the card's `src` attribute to 'images/astart.png' which is not the same as the `src` values in the `cardArray`.

So to get and set each the image links to each of `src` attributes, we use these line instead:

```js
card.setAttribute('src', cardArray[i]['img']);
```

...which would get the value of '`img`' in each of cards in the `cardArray`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, i made those changes and the pictures are still not loading.

Comment: Oh! Sorry for that... I've updated this answer, and it should do the trick! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of shuffling your cards.

```js
//create cards
const cardArray = [{name:'bass',img:'https://picsum.photos/200'},{name:'bass',img:'https://picsum.photos/201'},{name:'burger',img:'https://picsum.photos/202'},{name:'burger',img:'https://picsum.photos/203'},{name:'jamaica',img:'https://picsum.photos/204'},{name:'jamaica',img:'https://picsum.photos/205'},{name:'mbappe',img:'https://picsum.photos/206'},{name:'mbappe',img:'https://picsum.photos/207'},{name:'napali',img:'https://picsum.photos/208'},{name:"napali",img:'https://picsum.photos/209'},{name:'racecar',img:'https://picsum.photos/210'},{name:'racecar',img:'https://picsum.photos/211'}];
//shuffle from shfl-btn
document.getElementById('shfl-btn').addEventListener('click', createBoard);
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');

// Durstenfeld shuffle
// https://medium.com/@anthonyfuentes/do-the-shuffle-the-durstenfeld-shuffle-7920c2ce0c45
function shfl(a){
 for(let j,i=a.length;i>1;){
  j=Math.floor(Math.random()*i--);
  if (i!=j) [a[i],a[j]]=[a[j],a[i]]
 }
 return a
}
//create cards board
function createBoard() {
  grid.innerHTML=shfl(cardArray).map(c=>`<img src="${c.img}" title="${c.name}">`).join("");
}
createBoard();
```

```css
body { box-sizing: border-box; align-items: center;}
img { height: 100px; width: 100px }
button { padding: 10px; width: 80px; border: solid black 2px; border-radius: 4px; cursor: pointer; margin-top: 20px;}
.grid { height: 300px; width: 400px; border: solid blue 4px; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: row; margin: 0 auto; border-radius: 10px;}
.shfl-btn { align-items: center; margin: 0 auto; width: 400px;}
.shuffle {margin-left: 160px;}
```

```html
<h1>Shuffle picture cards</h1>
<div class="grid" id="grid"></div>
<div class="shfl-btn"><button class="shuffle" id="shfl-btn">shuffle</button></div>
```

In my snippet I create the whole HTML of the grid in one go and apply it to the grid DOM element with a single `.innerHTML` assignment. This is very efficient as the jtml parsing will be done only once.

I also used a different shuffling algorithm (Durstenfeld, a variation of the Fisher-Yates shuffle).